integrate() function giving incorrect results in R
I tried to use integrate function in two slightly different manner. Both resulted in different answers.
dgpareto = Vectorize(function(x,a,l,k){
   gamma(a+k)*(l^a)*(x^(k-1))/(gamma(a)*gamma(k)*((l+x)^(a+k)))
})
pgpareto = function(q,a,l,k){
   integrate(dgpareto,lower = 0,upper = q,a=a,l=l,k=k)$value
}
pgpareto2 = function(q,a,l,k){
   integrate(dgpareto,0,q,a=a,l=l,k=k)$value
}
pgpareto(5,2,1,1)
#[1] 0.9722222
pgpareto2(5,2,1,1)
#[1] -0.3055556

The integrate() gives the correct / expected result when the limits are specified by lower = 0 and upper = q but gives incorrect results without it. lower and upper are 2nd and 3rd input to integrate so I expected that I can use their input values without naming them explicitly. Whats the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

as revealed by @nicola https://stackoverflow.com/a/78544509/12158757, your problem is caused by the feature of argument partial matching. To avoid it, you can use L, for example, to distinguish the argument name from l(ower)  in integrate

It's a subtle annoyance and it has to do with argument partial matching. Consider this:
integrate(dnorm, u = 1, l = 0)$value
#[1] 0.3413447

As you can see, R partially matched the u argument as upper and l for lower.
Same happened in your case. You meant the l argument as the integrand function argument; instead, R intended that as the lower argument of integrate. So 0 became the first non named argument (and so upper), while the q value was used as the l argument of the integrand function.

Have a look at
> str(pgpareto(5,2,1,1))
List of 5
 $ value       : num 0.972
 $ abs.error   : num 3.81e-05
 $ subdivisions: int 1
 $ message     : chr "OK"
 $ call        : language integrate(f = dgpareto, lower = 0, upper = q, a = a, l = l, k = k)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"

> str(pgpareto2(5,2,1,1))
List of 5
 $ value       : num -0.306
 $ abs.error   : num 3.39e-15
 $ subdivisions: int 1
 $ message     : chr "OK"
 $ call        : language integrate(f = dgpareto, lower = l, upper = 0, q, a = a, k = k)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"

and compare the $calls.
